# Can't install Dropbox after upgrading to 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, dropbox

I had `Dropbox` working perfectly under `14.04 LTS`. After a fresh install of `16.04 LTS`, I downloaded and installed the `Dropbox` package and ran `dropbox start -i`. However, it showed an error that my internet connection might be down or I do not have correct proxy settings. (Neither is true: my connection is up and I do not use a proxy.)

Also, it outputs to the terminal:

`Starting Dropbox...<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)>`

What could be the problem and what can I do to resolve it?

Comment: How about installing Dropbox using `sudo apt install nautilus-dropbox` instead?

Comment: If you use default Ubuntu or Ubuntu-Gnome better use nautilus-dropbox and if you use Ubuntu-MATE better use caja-dropbox. Try to delete the folders `~/.dropbox` and `~/.dropbox-dist` and reboot.

Answer (score 5):

*Note: These packages install an open-source helper application. The version of this application does not change as frequently as the main Dropbox application. These packages will always install the latest version of Dropbox for Linux.View release notes*

**Dropbox Headless Install via command line**
The Dropbox daemon works fine on all 32-bit and 64-bit Linux servers. To install, run the following command in your Linux terminal.

**32-bit:**

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -
```

**64-bit:**

```
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -
```

Next, run the Dropbox daemon from the newly created .dropbox-dist folder.

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

If you're running Dropbox on your server for the first time, you'll be asked to copy and paste a link in a working browser to create a new account or add your server to an existing account. Once you do, your Dropbox folder will be created in your home directory. Download this [Python script](https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/dropbox.py) to control Dropbox from the command line. For easy access, put a symlink to the script anywhere in your PATH.

Source: https://www.dropbox.com/install

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 uses a totally different daemon system to 14.04 and dropbox hasn't made an install script to handle it. I can't leave a comment because I don't have 50 reputation but the answer for Ubuntu 16.04 has been answered here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/806445/unable-to-run-dropbox-daemon-at-boot

Answer (score 3):

I hope your problem has been resolved, if not this may help. I was also not able to use dropbox but this helped me a lot.

Install the .deb file of dropbox from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx).

Then after download, right click and select Open with software install.

Then install it.[image] You are done and start drop box and you will get little dropbox icon on top right.

References: Ref: https://www.linuxbabe.com/cloud-storage/install-dropbox-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the same problem for me.

Removed all packages relating to Dropbox.

Delete the .dropbox and .dropbox-dist directories in the Home directories.

Re-install nautilus-dropbox.

Goto dash either enter "Dropbox" or select the Dropbox icon from the Dashboard.

Follow the instructions and hey presto.

Answer (score 0):

Same general problem on Dropbox (DB) install.
Did the .tar download & install but did not proceed to registration page in automatically opened tab in Chrome.
Did command line install but again could not progress to registering machine to DB account. 
The Chrome browser would open but would not connect to Dropbox registration.
Discovered, by opening the developer tools, that certain Chrome extensions were not functioning. Uninstalled Chrome and opened Firefox.
Clicking on DB icon on top of desktop window revealed a "sign-in" option and when this was clicked FireFox opened a tab with DB login.
Successfully logged-in.